# Use Select from 2 databases then put results into one php do function

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to select data from 2 databases then use php do I just want to give an example that will explain every thing:

php code:

- first database name is comments.

`$colname_Program = "Any title from programs table :)";
mysql_select_db($database_Comments, $Comments);
$comments = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM programs WHERE title = "$colname_Program"', $Comments) or die(mysql_error());
$row_comments = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments);
$totalRows_comments = mysql_num_rows($comments);
$commentuserid = $row_comments['userid'];`

- "userid" is the id of the user which i will use in my second select from another database"

All what im trying to do from second select is to bring user information from second database using his id.

- Second database name is naitreno.

`mysql_select_db($database_NaiTreNo, $NaiTreNo);
$commentsuser = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = "$commentsuserid"', $Comments) or die(mysql_error());
$row_commentsuser = mysql_fetch_assoc($commentsuser);
$username = $row_commentsuser['UserName'];`

html and php code bundle now:

`<?php do { ?>
<div class="comment-text"><?php echo $username;?></div>>
<?php } while ($row_comments = mysql_fetch_assoc($comments)); }?>`

The code is not working :O what have I done wrong or what i have to do its just showing the first username in html`<div class="comment-text"></div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to union. UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Deepak for answering but the answer which I found is really very similar as your opinion, I  used  SQL" INNER Join " and that solved every thing.